# updateOrCreate return duplicate error while it should update

Tags: laravel-5

My understanding of Laravel **updateOrCreate** is that if a given value exists updates the table otherwise adds a new record **but** I have encounter as situation that instead of updating it give me the duplicate error. This is what I have:

```
$e = \App\Element::updateOrCreate(
                ['link' => $link],
                ['title'=>$title,'description' => $description]
```

This works fine but for one record I get:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'blahblahblah' for key 'link'
```

I wonder why updateOrCreate doesn't work here as it should. Shouldn't it leave the `link` column as it is and update the rest?

Comment: May be check whether values have spaces at the beginning or end

Comment: Thanks Saumini. Your hint indirectly solved my problem. In order to find the answer to your question I  checked both values inside the database and the value I wanted to insert and found out that the column on the database has the lenght of 255 weather the value I wanted to add is longer. So at first the laravel doesn't realize that they are the same but when mysql concat the link and tries to insert it they became the same hence the error message. So either I have to increase the size of the column or shorten the value before trying to insert it.

Comment: It seems that there are SQL race conditions causing this issue. There is a bug report for this: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/19372